# Adicionar timezones personalizados no PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

### TL;DR

Existe alguma maneira de adicionar `timezones` personalizados no PHP?

### Objetivo

Gostaria de poder registrar um horário (usando `new DateTime(...)`) com um valor arbitrário de offset de tempo (timezone), como por exemplo **13 minutos**, **51 minutos** ou **3 horas e 27 minutos**, para poder usar o método `DateTime::diff()` para calcular o intervalo de tempo entre dois eventos registrados por ***dois relógios distintos*** que podem estar dessincronizados entre si por uma diferença arbitrária (mas conhecida) de tempo.

### Exemplo prático:

**Evento 1**: 17h40min (registrado por relógio 1)

**Evento 2**: 19h40min (registrado por relógio 2, que está 4 minutos atrasado em relação ao relógio 1)

**Intervalo de tempo entre os eventos**: 2 horas e 4 minutos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu já li de [Dercik Rethans](http://derickrethans.nl/), que desenvolveu grande parte da classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php), até 2010 ['criar uma timezone personalizada' nem era cogitado por ele](http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html). Unindo isto à [atual documentação da DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php), entendo que ainda não é possível criar uma timezone específica (por padrão). Ainda assim, as respostas de *[mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr)* e *[Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio)* são alternativas.

Comment: Era uma resposta desse tipo que eu estava esperando. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Talvez o que você podia usar, para além da possibilidade que o *[mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr)* indicou, é o [**modify**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

Assim podia mudar o objecto DateTime para lhe dar a data modificada com a diferença inserida.

Exemplo:

```php
$data1 = new DateTime();
$data2 = new DateTime();
$data2->modify("+124 minutes");

$diferenca = $data2->diff($data1);
$resultado = $diferenca->format('%y Anos %m meses %a dias %h horas %i minutos %S segundos');
echo $resultado; // dá 0 Anos 0 meses 0 dias 2 horas 4 minutos 00 segundos
```

[**Examplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/02v-bcv)

Comment: Não conhecia esse `modify`, de fato é bem mais simples que minha solução. +1

Answer (score 3):

Não conheço nenhuma maneira de se criar `timezones` personalizados, mas posso sugerir uma alternativa usando timestamps.

1. Converta sua data para um timestamp (`int`), via [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) (se sua data estiver no formato `string`) ou [`DateTime::getTimestamp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) (se estiver nesse formato):

   ```php
    $timestamp1 = strtotime($hora1);
    $timestamp2 = $hora2->getTimestamp();
   ```
2. [Ajuste a diferença em segundos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709539/520779) de um deles (ou ambos):

   ```php
    function ajustar($timestamp, $horas = 0, $minutos = 0, $segundos = 0)
    {
        return $timestamp + ($segundos + 60 * ($minutos + 60 * $horas);
    }

    $timestamp1_ajustado = ajustar($timestamp1);
    $timestamp2_ajustado = ajustar($timestamp1, 0, 4);
   ```
3. Converta-os de novo para um `DateTime`, usando [`DateTime::setTimestamp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php):

   ```php
    $hora1_ajustada = new DateTime();
    $hora1_ajustada->setTimestamp($timestamp1_ajustado);

    $hora2_ajustada = new DateTime();
    $hora2_ajustada->setTimestamp($timestamp2_ajustado);
   ```

Agora você pode calcular a diferença entre elas normalmente. Código completo:

```php
function diferenca_ajustada($hora1, $hora2, $horas = 0, $minutos = 0, $segundos = 0)
{
    $timestamp1 = $hora1->getTimestamp();
    $timestamp2 = $hora2->getTimestamp() + $segundos + 60*($minutos + 60*$horas);

    $ajustada1 = new DateTime();
    $ajustada1->setTimestamp($timestamp1);
    $ajustada2 = new DateTime();
    $ajustada2->setTimestamp($timestamp2);

    return $ajustada1->diff($ajustada2);
}
```

[Exemplo no PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/bxq-8dc). Nota: se as datas estiverem em timezones diferentes, pode ser necessário primeiro convertê-las para UTC antes de compará-las:

```php
function para_utc($timestamp)
{
    return $timestamp - date("Z", $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela sua resposta, mostrou bastante esforço. Atualmente, o que eu estou fazendo já é mais ou menos isso mesmo: estou compensando os offsets de forma manual. No entanto, a ideia da pergunta é tentar descobrir como fazer isso usando a classe DateTime e seu método DateTime::diff(), o que ficaria muito mais limpo e organizado, e que só é possível configurando timezones arbitrários.

Comment: De qualquer jeito, você respondeu minha pergunta na primeira linha ("Não conheço nenhuma maneira de se criar timezones personalizados"), então se ninguém mais conhecer algum jeito de fazer isso, marco a sua resposta como aceita.

Comment: @pagliuca Eu imaginei isso, mas como procurei bastante e não achei nenhum jeito de fazer com timezones, reuni o que encontrei e montei uma alternativa... Mas me fala, você acha que usar timezones faz sentido [semanticamente]? Pra mim um timezone era pra ser uma coisa padronizada, talvez por isso não tenha um jeito fácil de criar timezones arbitrários (inclusive variando o minuto). Dê uma olhada [nessa lista](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php) pra ver o que é atualmente suportado (não se esqueça de clicar nos links pras listas completas).